# ABCpdf with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pdf, abcpdf

Trying to render pdf pages using ABCpdf within an angularjs application. Since some of my charts are heavy, they take a bit of time to render. ABCpdf tends to generate before my pages have a chance to fully render and result in empty/half rendered pdf pages.

Has anyone dealt with this issue before? We've tried to implement a time delay but that still doesn't solve the issue as we're not fully sure how long the charts would actually need. I also think ABCpdf throws an error if the delay is over 10-15 seconds.

Many thanks

Comment: Please post an example and/or code.

Comment: did you enable script by setting `UseScript = true;` ? Also try increasing the `Timeout` (default is 15500 ms = 15.5 s) http://www.websupergoo.com/helppdfnet/source/5-abcpdf/xhtmloptions/2-properties/timeout.htm

Comment: ABCpdf can operate with AJAX based charts but you will probably need to be using the current release. I suspect you need to upgrade.

Comment: @Maria how you resolved your issue?  am also facing same issue

Comment: Maria, what did you find?!